# UK Student Visa Type

Tags: visas, uk, student-visas

In my student visa the type is mentioned as D - Student and it is D - Student (S) for my friend. What is the difference between the two?

TIA.

Comment: Is the course length the same for both of you? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/854601/visa-vignettes-used-for-certain-categories-of-UK-visas-Dec-19.pdf